# How to adjust manipulate output in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

[image]

Is it possible to adjust manipulate option, so that this formula is written in a standard form: 5 Cos(2x + 1.85982), I mean that inside parentheses it is firstly written x, and then phase.

Also is there a way that this phase is written in terms of Pi, because I think it's more meaningful for students to see phase in familiar form Pi/2 than 1.5708.

Thank you for any suggestions and answers.

Here is the code that I used:

```
Manipulate[
     Plot[A Cos[\[Omega] t + \[Phi]], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 10], 
     Dynamic[A Cos[\[Omega] x + \[Phi]]], {{A, 5}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
     {\[Omega], 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
     {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[A Cos[\[Omega] t + \[Phi]], {t, -4 Pi, 4 Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 10], 
 Pane[Dynamic[A Cos[Row[{\[Omega] x, "+", \[Phi]}]]], {100, 30}],
 {{A, 5}, 1, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {\[Omega], 1, 5, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Screenshot:

[image: rational phase]

Answer (score 2):

In practice one prefers to control continuously the phase and amplitude. So to achieve expected results we add a trick which might be desired, by using `HoldForm[expr]` preventing evaluation of `expr` :

```
Manipulate[ 
    Plot[A Cos[\[Omega] t + \[Phi]], {t, -4Pi, 4Pi}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> 10],
    Pane[Dynamic[ A Cos[Row[{ \[Omega] x, "+", \[Phi]/Pi  HoldForm[Pi]}]]], {150, 30}],
    {{A, 5}, 1, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
    {\[Omega], 0.1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {\[Phi]  , 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for sharing this trick :) if someone tries this, he may encounter the problem that formula (see on picture in question what is formula) might not be whole visible, as I have. To fix it I just made box for it bigger by changing dimensions in Pane[______, {150,30}]. I've changed it to {170,30}.. and it works nice